# goBack on multiple routes with 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

For example, my browser history looks like this:

/page1 > /page2 > /page3 > /page4 > /page5

I want to navigate to /page2 from /page5, and then navigate to /page1 with `history.goBack()` function. I tried `go(-3)`, but it works just like `push()`. I need something like `goBack(-3)` or `replace(-3)`,
or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways to redirect to the pages.

1. props.histrory.push() // in push method you can pass routes specified in app
2. Can use component called Redirect ex: <Redirect to={''} />